# What is the best way to manage scheduled notifications in Android Studio?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I'm developing an Android app that keeps track of a users habits and sends scheduled reminders to the user even when the app has been removed from the recent app list. This is the problem I've been struggling with. I've tried using NotificationManager and AlarmManager alongside each other with a BroadcastReceiver, but I was unable to get any notifications when the app was closed. Now, I'm attempting to use Firebase Cloud Messaging which can send "messages" to the user even with the app closed, but I can't find any resources to create per-user scheduled "messages" directly from the app to my Firebase. I feel like I'm running in circles and I can't figure out how to have the user create their own scheduled notifications that work when the app hasn't been opened at all. Any suggestions?

Comment: `I can't figure out how to have the user create their own scheduled notifications that work when the app hasn't been opened at all` - doesn't make sense, the app needs to be opened at least once. See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client and specifically `Keep in mind that, to take advantage of these features, you'll need a server implementation and the server procotols (HTTP or XMPP), or an implementation of the Admin SDK.` OR if on device alarms be aware of https://dontkillmyapp.com/

Comment: Scheduled messages can only be sent from the Firebase console at the moment. When using the API, you'll have to take care of the scheduling yourself. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-cloud-messaging%5D+schedule